# Border at bottom of parallax website

Tags: html, css, border

Im having trouble getting rid of the border at the bottom of my website, www.goodlord.co. It is a single page scroller.

The last image is the problem I need to extend it to the end of the whole website but each time i do that the website its self extends. I would really appreciate any help.

Tom

This is the Style Sheet for the section css.

```
section{ background: #fff;  }
body{ -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; #fefefe; }
#main-container{ overflow: hidden; }
input{ -webkit-appearance: none; }
input:focus{ outline: none; }
.nopad{ padding: 0px; }
.offix{ overflow: hidden; }
.pad-normal{ padding-top: 66px; padding-bottom: 34px; }
.pad-large{ padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 60px; }
.pad-end{ padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 60px; }
.pad-large-top{ padding-top: 99px; }
.pad-large-bottom{ padding-bottom: 99px; }
.pad-top{ padding-top: 66px; }
.pad-bottom{ padding-bottom: 66px; }
.space-top{ margin-top: 22px; }
.space-top-large{ margin-top: 44px; }
::selection {color:#fff;background:#444444;}
::-moz-selection {color:#fff;background:#444444;}
```

This is the index for the section.

```
<a id="contact-scroll"></a>
        <section id="contact" class="text-divider bg-cover pad-end">

            <img alt="Slider Background" class="divider-bg" src="img/estate.jpg" />
            <div class="divider-overlay"></div>

            <div class="row divider-content">
            </div>

            <div class="row divider-content">
                <div class="medium-8 medium-centered columns">
                    <form id="contact-form" class="text-center">
                        <h1 class="text-white">Get in touch</h1>
                        <input id="form-name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                        <input id="form-email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input id="form-msg" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <span id="details-error" class="text-white">*Error: Please complete all fields correctly</span>
                            <span id="form-sent" class="text-white">Thankyou, your enquiry has been sent!</span>
                            <div class="btn white-btn clear-btn"><h6 class="alt-h text-white">Clear</h6></div>
                            <div id="form-btn" class="btn white-btn"><h6 class="alt-h text-white">Send</h6></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you give us more concrete explanation of what you mean by "I need to extend it to the end of the whole website" also "the website itself extends"

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that I would like the final image of the sofa to be the end of the website. Im not sure if i should stretch it or reduce the length of the website.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look, that last white border is actually padding, not border.

the final section with ID '#work' has the '.pad-large' class on it. remove it and the final image should butt up right to the bottom of the page.

You might need to restore the top padding of the item, as .pad-large adds 60px padding to the top and bottom of the item.

Comment: Thank you very much that was the problem. I was editing the ID#client section but it was part of a larger section. I created a new class .pad-end with 60px at the top and 0px at the bottom. 

Thanks again.

Comment: no worries. For the future, the easiest way to diagnose CSS bugs is to use the element inspector that comes with every browsers develop mode. Just point it at the element in question and it will show you what classes apply to an element as well as its spacing, size and CSS attributes.